# Capture Image as Array with Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I've seen from the sample how to display an image from the webcam, but how do I get the image captured as an array?

```
import cv

capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
img = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
```

img.tostring() gives me weird caracters.
Thanks in adv.

Comment: why do you want to capture it in array? whats the exact requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
img=cv.LoadImage("asd.png")
mat=cv.GetMat(img)
mat[3,1]
(83.0, 88.0, 89.0)
```

anyway, you should check opencv python [cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516134) for use with PIL and NUMPY packages.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to get an opencv with numpy support included. The sequence that works for me is capture an IPL, convert to cvMat, convert to numpy:

```
import cv, numpy, pylab
capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
img = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
mat=cv.GetMat(img)
a = numpy.asarray(mat)
pylab.imshow(a)
```

Note that the representation of color is different from what pylab assumes. But there comes [opencv documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/imgproc_miscellaneous_image_transformations.html?highlight=hsv#cvtcolor) to your help!

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem might be the way you are printing/displaying the contents of the array.

Nevertheless, [this blog post](http://www.jperla.com/blog/2007/09/26/capturing-frames-from-a-webcam-on-linux) shows how to capture frames from a webcam on linux using python.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, [QueryFrame](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=queryframe#QueryFrame) returns an [IplImage](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/basic_structures.html?highlight=iplimage#IplImage).  IplImage can be treated as an [arbitrary array](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/basic_structures.html?highlight=iplimage#cvarr).  It looks like you'll want to use the ["Get" set of functions](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=get2d#Get2D) to access array elements.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't knew how to manipulate it. I had found a way to convert it to a PIL image and then accesses as an array.

img_array = Image.fromstring("RGBA",cv.GetSize(img), img.tostring() )