# Using Python OpenCV Moments Function With An Image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to use the Python *opencv* function `Moments()` on a grayscale image, but I receive the following `TypeError`:

```
>>> img = cv.LoadImage('example_image.jpg', cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
>>> moments = cv.Moments(img)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Argument '' must be CvSeq, CvArr, or a sequence of numbers
>>>
```

I am confident this usage is correct as it is demonstrated in the *opencv* docs [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/imgproc_structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=distance#gethumoments), where `GetHuMoments()` uses the results from `Moments()`.

I believe I have *opencv* and *numpy* installed correctly, as I have been successfully using them for many other things, and I encounter this on both OS X 10.6 and Red Hat 6.

The same question is [posed in the *opencv* user group](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/78197), but I don't want to convert the image to a contour first as the reply instructs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you  need  to force conversion from IplImage to cvMat

There was a previous question "Capture Image as Array with Python OpenCV"

[Capture Image as Array with Python OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528813/capture-image-as-array-with-python-opencv)

e.g for me

```
>>> mm=cv.Moments(img)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Argument '' must be CvSeq, CvArr, or a sequence of numbers
>>> mat=cv.GetMat(img)
>>> mm=cv.Moments(mat)
>>> mm.m00
181428.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Which python and opencv version are you using? I am getting working results on python 2.6.6 and opencv 2.1.0

```
~/Desktop$ ./opencv-test.py 

> `enter code here`/home/tyndyll/Desktop/opencv-test.py(8)<module>()
-> img = cv.LoadImage( 'iron-maiden-live-after-death-iron-maiden_1920x1200_79442.jpg', cv.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE )
(Pdb) n
> /home/tyndyll/Desktop/opencv-test.py(9)<module>()
-> moments = cv.Moments( img )
(Pdb) p img
<iplimage(nChannels=1 width=1920 height=1200 widthStep=1920 )>
(Pdb) n
> /home/tyndyll/Desktop/opencv-test.py(10)<module>()
-> print "Done"
(Pdb) p moments
<cv.cvmoments object at 0x7f31fb5437b0>
(Pdb) c
Done
```